# Ubuntu boot with Windows 8.1, can't get Windows back

Tags: partitioning, windows-8

I installed Ubuntu earlier today, and can not find a way to go back to Windows. I have put the USB drive with Ubuntu on it, no option from GRUB, and I can't find it in Ubuntu either. I don't have an install disk, and I have my 8.1 side for my HDD available to look at and edit, but no way to go back to Windows. I need help.

Answer (score -1):

Did you define a partition. If not it will take some work. I tried installing Ubuntu with out making a partition and it took me a week to fix it.

Comment: I did, I have 167 gig for the Ubuntu side of my HDD, 20 gig for the root ans ~600 gig for Windows